# Need assistance in tuning the query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```sql
SELECT                 
                             DISTINCT cs_id
                                    , purchase_id
                                    , purchase_order_id
                                    , NVL(TRY_TO_NUMBER(price_id),0) AS price_id
                                    , NVL(TRY_TO_NUMBER(b_qno),0) AS b_qno
                                    , pp_list
                                    , NVL(ROUND(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE(CASE WHEN pp_list LIKE '20341%' THEN REPLACE(pp_list,'20341=','') END,';103=','') , '[^0-9^.,]', 0)),2),0) AS item_price_amt
            FROM (
            SELECT cs_id
                 , CASE WHEN order_qty='' THEN NULL ELSE order_qty END AS b_qno
                 , d.value::string AS pp_list
                 , purchase_id
                 , purchase_order_id
                 , price_id
                 FROM (
                        SELECT other.cs_id
                             , other.purchase_id
                             , purchase_order_id_p100 AS purchase_order_id
                             , split_part(c.value::string,';',2) price_id
                             , split_part(c.value::string,';',3) order_qty
                             , c.value::string AS item_list
                        FROM table_1 A 
                        JOIN table_2 B 
                          ON A.cs_id = B.cs_id
                        JOIN LATERAL flatten(INPUT=>split(item_list, ',')) c 
                        WHERE create_dt BETWEEN '2021-10-01' AND '2021-10-01'
                     ), LATERAL flatten(INPUT=>split(item_list, '|')) d
                 WHERE 1=1 AND price_id IS NOT NULL )
```

Is there anyway to rewrite the query in a simple way? The above query is taking long time to execute. I need to rewrite the query so that the performance would be faster.

Comment: The innermost query appears to possibly have a Cartesian product, and I suspect your use of DISTINCT on the outermost query is there to remove duplicates retrospectively.  Start with the innermost query and work your way outward.  While your inline tables for A and B have a join condition, C does not.  Also, please use aliases for the multi-table queries.  It's unclear which table create_dt is associated with.  Might want to also put those table DDLs in the mix here with some sample data.

Comment: In addition to the possible Cartesian product with the C inline table, you also have the same with the D inline table, as there is no join condition present with the prior query.  What would help again is the table DDL and sample data for table_1, table_2, and item_list.  You also have aliases to unreferenced tables (e.g., "other").

Comment: Last comment from me until there is additional information provided per prior requests - please use objective measures rather than subjective ones.  Saying a query takes "a long time" doesn't give us context.  Tell us how long it takes in seconds, minutes, hours, etc.  Provide row counts on tables to give us scale.  Look at the query profile and / or explain plan on the query and share that here as well.

Comment: where does the `other` table come from, aka `other.cs_id` and `other.purchase_id`, and what table does `purchase_order_id_p100` come from.  the `item_list` in `JOIN LATERAL flatten(INPUT=>split(item_list, ',')) c` what table does that come from? and `create_dt` what table does that come from?

Comment: You have two lateral flattens, and one is splitting a string. This is going to be slow. Flattening should be done one of two ways -- 1) For rare / ad hoc flattening, flatten in the query. 2) For regular / frequent flattening, flatten in the ETL/ELT pipeline, not the query.